# Ruby on Rails: FileUtils relative to server root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, directory, fileutils

When using PHP, any file manipulation is done relative to the server root, so something like `mkdir("/home/website/public_html/a_directory` would be used to create a directory in the public_html folder where the script is executed from.

In Rails, using the FileUtils module, it is relative to the Application's path like `FileUtils.mkdir('public/a_directory')` which will create a folder in the public folder of the application.

The problem I face is that from my Application, I would like to be able to create directories, move files, rename files/folders and remove file/folders relative to the server's root.

What's the best way to achieve this? OR am I missing something obvious?

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute paths in `FileUtil`:

```
FileUtil.mkdir('/tmp/foo')
```

will create the directory `foo` in then servers `/tmp/` directory.

`Rail.root` holds the root of your rails application.

You can extend the path like `Rails.root.join('public','a_directory')`.

Remember that the `DOCUMENT ROOT` is `Rails.root.join('public')`

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it properly. If I have my app hosted in `/home/website/public_html/my_app/`, I would like to be able to manipulate files / folders within `home/website/public_html/another_folder/`

Comment: if your Rails app is in `/home/website`, than your application is in `/home/website/app` and your `DOCUMENT ROOT` is in `/home/website/public`. Then `Rails.root` points to `/home/website` and you can build paths starting there.

Comment: Ah, now I think I understand your question, updating the answer

Comment: I think I've just discovered what will work.. It was blindingly obvious (i think). I just need to use a `/` at the beginning of my `FileUtils.mkdir()` function to relate it to the server root. If I do not use the `/` it relates to the root of the application.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I see where you were going with this answer. It will come in handy when switching between Staging and Production as I won't need to change my code to compensate.